# glGetAttribLocation works only sometimes

Tags: opengl, glsl

I can compile, link, and run GLSL programs, but can't extract handles to all the attributes.

```c
const std :: string v = shaders .read_file (VERTEX_SHADER);
const std :: string f = shaders .read_file (FRAGMENT_SHADER);

std :: cout
    << "Vertex shader:\n" << v
    << "Fragment shader:\n" << f
    << "End of shaders.\n";

// Create objects
auto f_id = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
auto v_id = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
auto p = glCreateProgram ();

// Success flags
GLint v_ok, f_ok, p_ok;

// Compile vertex shader
const GLchar * source = v .c_str ();
GLint length = v .size ();
glShaderSource (v_id, 1, & source, & length);
glCompileShader (v_id);
glGetShaderiv (v_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &v_ok);

// Compile fragment shader
source = f .c_str ();
length = f .size ();
glShaderSource (f_id, 1, & source, & length);
glCompileShader (f_id);
glGetShaderiv (f_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &f_ok);

// Link
glAttachShader (p, v_id);
glAttachShader (p, f_id);
glLinkProgram (p);
glGetProgramiv (p, GL_LINK_STATUS, &p_ok);

if (f_ok && v_ok && p_ok)
{
    std :: cout << "Build OK\n";

    for (auto n : {"normal", "position", "xxx", "fail"})
    {
        auto a = glGetAttribLocation (p, n);

        std :: cout << n <<" is " << a << std :: endl;
    }
}
else
    std :: cout << "Build failed.\n";

assert (GL_NO_ERROR == glGetError ());
```

I expect the "normal", "position", and "xxx" attributes to be located, but not "fail". Here is the output.

```
Vertex shader:
#version 130

attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 xxx;

void main ()
{
        gl_Position = vec4 (position, 1);
}
Fragment shader:
#version 130

out vec4 finalColor;

void main ()
{
        finalColor = vec4 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
End of shaders.
Build OK
normal is -1
position is 0
xxx is -1
fail is -1
```

When I actually run it, I get an untransformed white triangle as expected. Why is only "position" loaded correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's for the same reason that uniforms are only guaranteed to exist if they're used. Any uniforms, attributes, or other defined resources that go unused by your shader may not be there if you try to query them.